# preventing 'make clean' from ExternalProject or add a custom clean with CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, external-project

My project has an external project that I add with its own CMake with the CMake `ExternalProject_Add` command.

Every time I add flags or do a rebuild the external project is also rebuilt and it takes a long time
(rebuild of the external project includes extract and dynamic library build).

How do I prevent its rebuilding when we rebuild my project?

### ExternalProject.cmake:

```
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(project
    PREFIX              ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/external
    URL                 ${THIRD_PARTY_SRC}/archives/project.tar.gz
    INSTALL_DIR         ${THIRD_PARTY_SRC}/install
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND}    -E env
    ${EXTERNAL_PROJECT_TOOLS}
    <SOURCE_DIR>/configure.py
    --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
    ${EXTERNAL_PROJECT_CPU}
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
    )
```

### CMakelists.txt:

```
set(PROJECT externalProject)
add_library(externalProject SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET externalProject PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${THIRD_PARTY_SRC}/install/lib/externalProject.so)
```

Comment: Your title asks specifically about `make clean`, but the body of the question seems to be more general.  I am inclined to think that the behavior you describe is normal and expected, so perhaps the best way to address the situation is simply to avoid `make clean` when you don't need it (and you should rarely need it in a well-structured project).

Comment: Or perhaps you don't want an external project at all, but rather a wholly separate dependency.